# Compress JPG images with mini lose in quality & usage of smoothing

Tags: imagemagick, compression

Which Linux CLI tool is the best for compressing JPG images using a smoothing value for even better image size optimization? I didn't really get along with ImageMagick when it came to smoothing.

With Macromedia FireWorks for Windows, for example, you can select various settings for image export with which you can do this. The setting is called "JPEG Smaller File" and is preset to Quality 60 and Smoothing 2.

The results are excellent.

Is anyone familiar with it?

Comment: Please tell an example of how you compress JPG with ImageMagick? (The exact command line).

Comment: See also: https://dev.to/feldroy/til-strategies-for-compressing-jpg-files-with-imagemagick-5fn9

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  The way this is currently phrased, it invokes more "discussion" and "opinion" (which are [off-topic here](https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask)) rather than subjective answers.  Can you edit it to focus on one specific, quantifiable problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Thank you @all for your replies. First, sorry for the late response. I use ImageMagick as follows: `imagick file.jpg -gaussian-blur 0.01 -quality 80% fileout.jpg` As expected, the result is a compressed image with a acceptable file size. Only the quality cannot be seen when it comes to e.g. product images. If I try to go a lil bit lower with the quality, the result has a bigger markable lose in quality, even with a gaussian blur factor. What's wrong with my settings?